# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I have an error when running my application in Spring Boot, I've already researched cases like mine, however, none of them solved my problem, I'm running the application in Eclipse, using the Spring plugin, I've tried to run the application in Maven too, but i get the same error.

**Error message:**

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.backend.userapi.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.backend.userapi.repository.UserRepository.queryByNameLike(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.backend.userapi.repository.UserRepository.queryByNameLike(java.lang.String)! No property 'name' found for type 'User' Did you mean ''nome''; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.backend.userapi.repository.UserRepository.queryByNameLike(java.lang.String)! No property 'name' found for type 'User' Did you mean ''nome''
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at com.backend.userapi.LivroApplication.main(LivroApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
```

Below the lines of code for my class:

**User class**

```
package com.backend.userapi.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.backend.userapi.dto.UserDTO;

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String cpf;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String telephone;
    private Date dateRegister;
    
    public User() {}

    public User(long id, String name, String cpf, String address, String email, String telephone, Date dateRegister) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = name;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.endereco = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telephone;
        this.dataCadastro = dateRegister;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setName(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone= telephone;
    }
    public Date getDateRegister() {
        return dateRegister;
    }
    public void setDateRegister(Date dateRegister) {
        this.dateRegister= dateRegister;
    }
    
    public static User convert(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userDTO.getName());
        user.setAddress(userDTO.getAddress());
        user.setCpf(userDTO.getCpf());
        user.setEmail(userDTO.getEmail());
        user.setTelephone(userDTO.getTelephone());
        user.setDateRegister(userDTO.getDateRegister());
        
        return user;
        
    }
}
```

**Note: CPF is an identification number in Brazil**

**UserRepository Class**

```
package com.backend.userapi.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.backend.userapi.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByCpf(String cpf);
    
    List<User>queryByNameLike(String name);

}
```

**UserService Class**

```
package com.backend.userapi.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.backend.userapi.dto.UserDTO;
import com.backend.userapi.model.User;
import com.backend.userapi.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public List<UserDTO>getAll() {
        List<User> usuarios = userRepository.findAll();
        
        return usuarios.stream().map(UserDTO::convert).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    public UserDTO findById(long userId) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        
        if(user.isPresent()) {
            return UserDTO.convert(user.get());
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public UserDTO save(UserDTO userDTO) {
        User user = userRepository.save(User.convert(userDTO));
        
        return UserDTO.convert(user);
    }
    
    public UserDTO delete(long userId) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        
        if(user.isPresent()) {
            userRepository.delete(user.get());
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public UserDTO findByCpf(String cpf) {
        User user = userRepository.findByCpf(cpf);
        
        if(user != null) {
            UserDTO.convert(user);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
    public List<UserDTO>queryByName(String name) {
        List<User> user = userRepository.queryByNameLike(name);
        
        return user.stream().map(UserDTO::convert).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**UserController Class**

```
package com.backend.userapi.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.backend.userapi.dto.UserDTO;
import com.backend.userapi.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    public static List<UserDTO> user = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String message() {
        return "Spring boot is working";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/user/")
    public List<UserDTO>getUsers() {
        List<UserDTO> usuarios = userService.getAll();
        return user;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/user/{id}") 
    UserDTO findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/user/cpf/{cpf}")
    UserDTO findByCpf(@PathVariable String cpf) {
        return userService.findByCpf(cpf);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/user/search")
    public List<UserDTO>queryByName(@RequestParam(name="nome",required = true) String name) {
        return userService.queryByName(name);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/user/{id}")
    UserDTO delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userService.delete(id);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/user")
    UserDTO newUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        return userService.save(userDTO);
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void initiateList() {
        
        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setName("Alex");
        userDTO.setCpf("123");
        userDTO.setAddress("Road a");
        userDTO.setEmail("alex@gmail.com");
        userDTO.setTelephone("1234-2345");
        
        UserDTO userDTO2 = new UserDTO();
        userDTO2.setName("Maria");
        userDTO2.setCpf("234");
        userDTO2.setAddress("Road b");
        userDTO2.setEmail("maria@gmail.com");
        userDTO2.setTelephone("2585-2345");
        
        UserDTO userDTO3 = new UserDTO();
        userDTO3.setName("Jhon");
        userDTO3.setCpf("564");
        userDTO3.setAddress("Road c");
        userDTO3.setEmail("jhon@gmail.com");
        userDTO3.setTelephone("5578-5545");
        
        UserDTO userDTO4 = new UserDTO();
        userDTO4.setName("Rick");
        userDTO4.setCpf("896");
        userDTO4.setAddress("Road d");
        userDTO4.setEmail("rick@gmail.com");
        userDTO4.setTelephone("5487-6598");
        
        user.add(userDTO);
        user.add(userDTO2);
        user.add(userDTO3);
        user.add(userDTO4);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.livro</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>livro</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please review your code, edit your question to post your actual code if there is any difference with what you posted, and try again after recompiling all your code. The exception you've shown us clearly states that the problem is you're trying to query by a property `name` in your repository, that does not exist in your `User` entity. The constructor of said entity confirms this because you assign to `this.nome` in it, despite your entity as you've posted it having a `name` field and not a `nome` field. So, either your code doesn't compile, or it's different from the code you posted.

Comment: Did you scroll all the way to the right?  `No property 'name' found for type 'User'` appears to be the underlying reason.

Comment: I don't think your `User` class is getting compiled at all, please check and correct name field (currently it is nome), maybe this class is not the one you have, inside the jar, issue a clean install and see.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).